# Replace duplicate elements in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I want to replace duplicated elements within a group

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3))
```

I want to keep the first element of the group, while replacing anything else with NA. Something like:

```
df <- df %>% 
     group_by(group) %>%
     mutate(B = first(A))
```

Which doesn't produce what I want. What I want instead is `B <- c(a, NA, a, NA, NA, c)`

Comment: Do you intend to keep `A` as a `factor`? It'll change the answers a little if you do. (I typically use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, so when I see factors used I tend to ask for clarification.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `replace` with `duplicated`:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(B = replace(A, duplicated(A), NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
#       A group
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      a     1
#2     NA     1
#3      a     2
#4      b     2
#5     NA     2
#6      c     3
```

Or if keep only the first element:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(B = ifelse(row_number() == 1, as.character(A), NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
#      A group
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1     a     1
#2  <NA>     1
#3     a     2
#4  <NA>     2
#5  <NA>     2
#6     c     3
```

OR use `replace`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(B = replace(A, row_number() > 1, NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
#       A group
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1      a     1
#2     NA     1
#3      a     2
#4     NA     2
#5     NA     2
#6      c     3
```

Comment: But that's not what the OP is expecting.

Comment: @r2evans I was looking at his statement. *replace duplicated elements within a group*. But yeah, it's not certain what OP wants exactly.

Comment: I'll correct myself ... it is not the vector the OP showed as expected, whether or not it is what is desired. What is requested and what is needed are not always the same. :-)

Comment: @r2evans Yes. I've modified the answer to cope with the factor data type.

Comment: I think I like `replace` better, since it transfers the `factor` and levels with it instead of assuming and/or coercing. But that's mostly me projecting my style, preferring to not assume and/or coerce types if I can avoid it.

Comment: @r2evans I think so as well. Added `replace` option to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table` you could do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, B := c(A[1], rep(NA, .N - 1)), by = group]
```

Or same logic in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(B = c(as.character(A[1]), rep(NA, n() - 1)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#       A group     B
#  <fctr> <dbl> <chr>
#1      a     1     a
#2      a     1  <NA>
#3      a     2     a
#4      b     2  <NA>
#5      b     2  <NA>
#6      c     3     c
```